# having issues adding an input to an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a problem that I think is asking me to have a user enter a input into a array. I am having difficulties understanding this and any help would be appreciated.

The problem is as follows:

Design a program that lets the user enter the total rainfall for each of 12 months into an array. The program should calculate and display the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall, and the months with the highest and lowest amounts.

Here is what I have wrote so far:

```
def get_rainfall(a, b)
  rain_array = []
  rain_array.push(a => b)
  puts rain_array
end

get_rainfall('january', 300)
```

Comment: Hey @C_B - thanks for posting. It would be great if you could show the code you've written so far. SO is designed to help overcome specific issues and having your workings to date really helps. There's a great guide on writing a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that's well worth a read :) That said, here are the docs for [`<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) and [`push`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-push) which should help get you started.

Comment: Here is the small amount I have so far from messing around with it.

Comment: def get_rainfall(a, b) 
    rain_array = []
    rain_array.push(a => b)
    puts rain_array
end

get_rainfall('january', 300)

Comment: @C_B There is no issue addressing questions the comments, however if something provides additional clarification or info about the question itself it's better suited to [update the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55246812/edit) and notify the user that asked for the clarification that you've updated the question and provided the additional info.

Comment: Is there anything specific you have an issue with? Does the code behave different than expected? Don't you know how to ask the user for input? etc.

Comment: @C_B the code you have written keeps resetting the array to an empty array before appending the new data and returning it, so you will always get back what you put in. You may need a class to keep state in, or possibly a global variable.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I honestly do not understand how to ask the user to put inputs into an arrary and then all the mathematical functions at the end. For those functions do I have to do them to the array itself or ask for indexs.

Comment: I've added and answer, along with an update that gets the input from the user @C_B. Hope it's helpful. If you're still struggling, there's a great resource [here](https://www.codecademy.com/catalog/language/ruby) which is worth running through and I'm sure will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for updating the question C_B.

I think the slight issue you're having here is between hashes and arrays.

Your current method results in the following:

```
#=> [{"january"=>300}, {"february"=>...}]
```

This happens because when you call `rain_array.push(a => b)`, you're pushing a hash to the array each time in `a => b`.

It seems to me you'd be better suited storing the whole things as a hash, perhaps:

```
hash = {}

def get_rainfall(hash, key, value)
  hash[key] = value
  puts hash
end

get_rainfall(hash, 'january', 300)
# {"january"=>300}

get_rainfall(hash, 'february', 200)
#{"january"=>300, "february"=>200}
```

Hash you add more entries, they will be stored under the month as the key, with the rainfall as the value.

Alternatively, you could also push an array of arrays - to tweak your current method:

```
rain_array = []

def get_rainfall(array, a, b)
  array.push([a, b])
  puts array
end

get_rainfall(rain_array, 'january', 300)
# january
# 300

get_rainfall(rain_array, 'february', 200)
# january
# 300
# february
# 200
```

You'll notice I'm pulling the declaration of the array or hash to store the values outside of the method; without this, you'll lose access to it as soon as the method has run.

Hope that helps - happy to expand if you've any questions or queries. Let me know how you get on.

---

One more update based on a further comment about getting user input. Try the following to get you started:

```
hash = {}

def get_rainfall(hash, month)
  puts "Please enter value for #{month}"
  hash[month] = gets.chomp
  puts hash
end


get_rainfall(hash, 'january')
```

Comment: that help a lot. Is there a simpler way to ask the user for an input though or will it still need to be stored to do the equations at the n end of the problem?

Comment: There are many, many ways :) If you're using a very simple approach, this will work, though you could also accept input as a file, 12 values split on a single input etc. I'd suggest having a play with the short course I commented on your question, though hope this helps getting started! With this, if you run the method once for each month, you'll have a hash of data you can use to perform the calculations. (E.G. `hash.values.sum / hash.values.length`)

Comment: @C_B If you're always asking the users for an integer you could use `gets.to_i`. This also converts the value from a [*String*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html) into an [*Integer*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Integer.html). Keep in mind that the [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html#method-i-to_i) method does use `0` if no number is detected.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write my answer in simple script form to not over complicate what is being asked here.

The minimal approach is to not worry about month names for now and simply collect a list (array) of 12 values to do the calculations with.

```
rainfall = 1.upto(12).map do |month_nr|

  # `print` and `puts` are practically the same with the only difference being
  # that `puts` adds a newline character to the string if it doesn't have one

  # output the question to the user
  print "enter the rainfall for month #{month_nr}: "
  # get the input from the user and convert it into an integer
  gets.to_i # output the rainfall
end

puts "the total rainfall is: #{rainfall.sum}"
puts "the average rainfall is: #{rainfall.sum / rainfall.size}"
puts "the highest rainfall is: #{rainfall.max}"
puts "the lowest rainfall is: #{rainfall.min}"
```

If you care about month names you can do the following:

```
# create an array of all months
months = %w[January February March April May June July August September October November December]
# ask the user for each moth the amount of rainfall
rainfall = months.map do |month_name|
  print "enter the rainfall for month #{month_name}: "
  [month_name, gets.to_i] # output both the month name and the rainfall provided
end

# convert [['January', 123], ['February', 456], ...]
# to { 'January' => 123, 'February' => 456, ... }
rainfall = rainfall.to_h

puts "the total rainfall is: #{rainfall.values.sum}"
puts "the average rainfall is: #{rainfall.values.sum / rainfall.size}"
# search the key with the highest value
puts "the month with the highest rainfall is: #{rainfall.key(rainfall.values.max)}"
# search the key with the lowest value
puts "the month with the lowest rainfall is: #{rainfall.key(rainfall.values.min)}"
```

If anything is unclear have a look at the reference of the thing it is you have difficulty with. If it's still unclear ask away in the comments.

**references:**

- [String interpolation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) (`"1 + 1 = #{1 + 1}"`)
- [`Integer#upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Integer.html#method-i-upto)
- [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)
- [`Kernel#print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Kernel.html#method-i-print) output to standard output without appending newline
- [`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) read from standard input
- [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html#method-i-to_i)
- [`Kernel#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) output to standard output while appending a newline character (unless already present)
- [`Array#sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-sum)
- [`Array#size`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-size)
- [`Array#max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-max)
- [`Array#min`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-min)
- [`%w`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) array of strings
- [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-to_h) convert array to a hash
- [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html#method-i-values)
- [`Hash#key`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html#method-i-key)